# How to get Decimal and Thousand seperator of user personal settings in Sharepoint JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to get **Decimal** and **Thousand separator** of user personal settings in SharePoint JSOM

for example I can get date formatted using `SP.Utilities.Utility.formatDateTime` ...

IS there any way to get user's personal setting's Decimal Separator?

Comment: make no sense? user's personal setting's Decimal Separator?, do you mean return all user personal settings with decimal as the separator?

Comment: @Ali I asked that for a particular Region Locale there will be . or , as a decimal separator, I need that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably try something like this:

```
var number = 1000234.033;
var currentCulture = _spContextInfo.currentCultureName;
number.toLocaleString(currentCulture);
```

Also you could use `toLocaleString()` if the user is already on his/her locale region, it will pick that up.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString